# Better way of having a PayPal checkout?

Tags: php, paypal, checkout

I am working on a simple marketplace for my website. I currently have a PayPal checkout terminal that I built. It has a PayPal button and the form data in the source that's pulled from the database that redirects back to the website after the checkout to either a success or failure page.

I am a little concerned people might change around the hidden input values before submitting the form to PayPal, such as the total price.

Is there any way to send POST data via PHP through a secondary page?
(Such as **buy_now.php** -> **hidden_checkout.php** (hidden/secondary page with a header redirect) -> **paypal.com** (with all values).

Pretty much **hidden_checkout.php** will have all the variables fetched from the database and form data that isn't accessible by the user unless a post is done.

If anyone needs some code to look at, I am more than happy to edit my post and show it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick with Payments Standard you could do that sort of thing using the "[cart upload command method](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/cart_upload/)".  Your initial button could submit to your PHP script, which then compiles all the data into an HTTP request that gets posted to PayPal accordingly. This way you could check the pricing and things before it ever redirects to PayPal.

Another option, which I prefer, is to use the Express Checkout API's instead of Payments Standard.  This requires more coding knowledge and experience with web service API's in general, but the use of class libraries like my [PHP library for PayPal](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-php-library) can make it very simple for even novice PHP coders. It comes with fully functional samples, so you could get Express Checkout implemented pretty quickly and easily.

When working with the API's the user can't see any hidden fields or anything in the code. Express Checkout also has lots more features and fewer restrictions than PayPal Standard.